# XPath : Is it possible to return an empty String if elements are not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I use nokogiri(which in turn uses xpath) to parse xml file. xml has some data including "definition" for every element. Some of the child nodes does not have definition element.

Sample Example:

```
<parent>
  <definition> It is XYZ </definition>
</parent>
<parent>
  <definition> It is XYZ </definition>
</parent>
<parent>
</parent>
<parent>
  <definition> It is XYZ </definition>
</parent>
```

XPath like this '/parent/definition' will return an array only with 3 elements.

Here, 3rd element does not have definition element. I am querying for all the definitions. I want an array as output which will have first, second and forth element as "It is XYZ" and 3rd element should be empty string or nil. But I am getting only 3 elements in array with values of 1,2 and 4. I use this array later in my code. I want the third element to be blank. It is possible to achieve it?

Not sure if it matters, but xml contents keep changing every time I make a call. I mean, tags will be same but the number of elements and values will change. XML I am parsing is pretty big. One solution is to do querying each element in a loop. It worked fine but it takes too much time. So any solution with which I can get all definitions in one parse will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: oops sorry. I will edit the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 2.0:

```
parent/string(definition)
```

In XPath 1.0 - oh dear, why would anyone want to use XPath 1.0? ;-(

Comment: As soon as libxml2 supports XPath 2.0, nobody will have a need for 1.0 anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

To do as much as possible in the underlying libxml2,

```
doc.xpath('(parent/definition|parent[not(definition)])/text()')
```

Comment: Quote from the question: "One solution is to do querying each element in a loop. It worked fine but it takes too much time."

Comment: @NiklasB.You are correct. Made it an XPath solution so it is done completely in the libxml2 library.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting three elements because only three "/parent/definition" elements exist. If, under your third parent element, you had an empty definition node (i.e. `<definition/>`), then you would be getting results as you want them.
If you cannot restructure your XML to place default empty definition elements inside each parent, then you will need to alter your XPath to search for "/parent", and create a function that loops over each parent element and checks to see if a search for "definition" on each parent returns anything. If not, get the function to return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/parent/definition|/parent[not(definition)]
```

it means 'all the `/parent/definition` elements plus all the `/parent` elements that do not contain a `definition` sub-element